# Generate list of values from nested dictionary as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
d = {'A': {'A': 0.11, 'C': 0.12, 'D': 1.0}, 'B': {'B': 0.13, 'C': 0.14}}
```

I want to generate this output where in values only the list of keys of inner dictionary are selected.

output dictionary

```
output = {'A':['A', 'C', 'D'], 'B':['B', 'C']}
```

Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass each sub-dict to the `list` constructor to convert the keys to a list:

```
output = {k: list(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

@blhsing's answer is the way to go. This is also a way.

```
d = {'A': {'A': 0.11, 'C': 0.12, 'D': 1.0}, 'B': {'B': 0.13, 'C': 0.14}}

e={}
for k, v in d.items():
    e[k]=list(v.keys())

print(e)
#{'A': ['A', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['B', 'C']}
```